# CakePHP: Why am I unable to update record with set() or save()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I've been trying all night to update a record like this:

```
                $r = $this->Question->read(NULL, $question['Question']['id']);
                debug($r);// This is a complete Question array
                $this->Question->set('status', 'version');
                $s = $this->Question->save();
                //$s = $this->Question->save($r['Question']);//this also doesn't work
                debug($s); // = False every time!! Why??
                exit;
```

The two comments show variations I've tried but didn't work either.

@Dipesh:

```
                $this->data = $this->Question->read(NULL, $question['Question']['id']);
                $this->Question->status = 'version';
                $s = $this->Question->save($this->data);
                debug($s);
                exit;
```

@Dipesh II:

```
                $this->request->data = $this->Question->read(NULL, $question['Question']['id']);
                debug($this->data);
                //$this->Question->status = 'version';
                $this->request->data['Question']['status'] = 'version';
                $s = $this->Question->save($this->request->data);
                //$s = $this->Question->save($r['Question']);
                debug($s);
                exit;
```

@Dipesh III:
(removed)

Comment: Do you have validations set for Question? If so, can you do a `debug($this->Question->validationErrors)` right after `debug($s)`?

Comment: That's a good idea. I didn't know about that method. But did you see my answer below? Wouldn't validations apply to my solution too?

Comment: Yes, but my guess is that your solution is working because by adding all the data by hand, you may be validating correctly and therefore saving the question. Post your model in your question and let's see what we've got :)

Answer (score 1):

cakePHP provide a method called set() in both `Models::set()` as well as in `Controller::set();`

*About `Controller::set()`*
This method is used to set variables for view level from any of the controller method. For example fetching records and from models and setting them for views to display it to clients, like this

```
$data = $this->{ModelName}->find('first');
$this->set('dataForView',$data) // now you can access $data in your view as $dataForView
```

About Model::set()
This method is used to set data upon a model, the format of the array that will be passed must be same as that used in Model::save() method i.e. like this

```
$dataFormModel = array('ModelName'=>array('col_name'=>$colValue));
$this->{ModelName}->set($dataForModel);
```

`Model::set()` will accept its parameter only in this format, once successfully set you can do following

1. validate this data against the validation rules specified in model directly like this

   $isValid = $this->ModelName->validate();
2. save/update data by calling `Model::save()`

Comment: Thanks. For the Model::set(), how do we tell Cake which record we want to update? Does it take another parameter for `WHERE...`?

Comment: Simply set id of the model concerend like this $this->Model->id = $intVar

Comment: So run that id() method first? Before the set() and the save()?

Comment: id is not method it is model's class attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->data` instead of `$r`

**Example**

```
$this->data = $this->Question->read(NULL, $question['Question']['id']);
```

`$this->set` is used to set variable value and pass it to view so view can access it where as `$this->data` represent the data to be stored in database.

If You're using Cake 2.0 then replace `$this->data` which is read only in Cake 2.0 to `$this->request->data`.

Comment: Is that the only change I need to make to my code? Or do a I also `save($this->data)`?

Comment: @Emerson **replace** `$this->Question->status = 'version';` with `$this->data['Question']['status'] = 'version';`

Comment: It still returns false, but also with this Warning: `Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property QuestionsController::$data has no effect [APP/Controller/QuestionsController.php, line 151]
`

Comment: @Emerson ohhh you are using cakephp2 then use `$this->request->data`

Comment: Does it matter that I have used save() on a different record higher up in the code? This same function saves a few different records.

Comment: Still returns false. I updated with the new code. Maybe I got it wrong?

Comment: @Emerson no no no its not but yes if that has already have set some variable those are conflicting or resetting it.

Comment: Just added. Sorry it's really long. The code we're discussing is about 3/4 of the way down.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29281/discussion-between-dipesh-parmar-and-emerson)

Comment: Theres no reason to use `$this->request->data` instead of a local variable. You'll only use `$this->request->data` if you want to propagate the data to an edit-form. **However** when using multiple `save()` calls on the same model, *always* use [`Model::create()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array) to reset the model and prepare it for performing the next `save()`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very "automagical" but I was able to get this working like this:

```
$set_perm_id = 42;//who cares
$data = array(
            'Question'=> array(
                        'id'=> $question['Question']['id'],
                        'perm_id'=> $set_perm_id,
                        'status'=>'version'
                        )
            );
$s=$this->Question->save($data);
```

Basically I'm just building the data array manually. If anyone knows why this works instead of what I was doing before, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try these lines..

```
$this->Question->id =  $question['Question']['id'];
$this->Question->set('status','version');
$this->Question->save();
```

OR

```
$aUpdate["id"] = $question['Question']['id'];
$aUpdate["status"] = "version";
$this->Question->save($aUpdate);
```